# Postgres RDS read replica takes too long

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, read-replication

We currently running PostgresRDS on AWS with two read replica, the instance is db.m4.4xlarge. We created new read replica with similar size yesterday to help with the load but it's been in this status: "Streaming replication has stopped." for over a day and the lag time only goes up.

Previously when we created read replica, after creation they were in similar state but it caught up after few hours. Any idea if there is a better way to get the real status of the read replica? why is the lag only grows even when we stopped writing to the master postgres.

It's not the first time we encounter the problem and the lack of real status/state is really annoying.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is a question better asked on the AWS Forum or opening a support ticket with AWS.